# Reset an Action Button back to NULL

Tags: r, shiny

how can a person reset the actionButton back to being selected = character(0) rather than one of the radio buttons that they have available,

any idea?

Comment: Please provide sample code as im not clear where radiobuttons come in

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use an action button to reset a radio button? Try using `updateRadioButton` (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateRadioButtons.html). Here is an example:

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("radio_buttons", "Radio buttons", list("option 1", "option 2"), 
                 selected = character(0)),
    actionButton("reset_button", "Reset button")
  )




)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$reset_button, {

    updateRadioButtons(session, "radio_buttons", "Radio buttons", list("option 1", "option 2"),
                       selected = character(0)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use shinyjs package for this,Thanks to Dean Attali for this wonderful package.

This is an example:

```
if (interactive()) {
     library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)

  shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),
   div(
   id = "form",
          textInput("name", "Name"),
           radioButtons("gender", "Gender", c("Male", "Female"))
         ),
        actionButton("resetAll", "Reset all"),
         actionButton("resetName", "Reset name"),
         actionButton("resetGender", "Reset Gender")
       ),
       server = function(input, output) {
         observeEvent(input$resetName, {
           reset("name")
         })
         observeEvent(input$resetGender, {
           reset("gender")
         })
         observeEvent(input$resetAll, {
           reset("form")
         })
      }
     )
   }
```

You can read about this in [here](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it is impossible to reset an actionButton in `shiny`.

You can consider incrementing a `reactiveValue` each time the button is clicked, and then checking if this value is odd or even to perform a given action.